# Load external photo with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the image source of an image object with javascript.

I have tried

```
<img src="" id="image" alt="">
<p id="change">Change</p>
```

```js
$("#change").click(function () {
  $("#image").attr("src", "some source");
});
```

The problem is that it seems it does change the src, but it doesn't work if the image wasn't loaded when the page loaded. So I cannot suddenly change to the logo of Stackoverflow. Can this be true? How can I then load the image while changing the source?

Comment: what are you changing `src` to?

Comment: Is this wrapped around a document load or a $(document).ready? Why would you change it if it hasn't even loaded yet?

Comment: It worked when I changed to `.attr("src", "some source").load()`

Comment: It is possible you are binding the `click` event when your `p` element is not present on the page?? Try to provide a working snippet that reproduces the issue so it would be easier to help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this a couple weeks ago, the easiest way I managed to solve the issue was by loading all image's you will need, and set all of the ones you don't need right away as hidden.  Then when your action that causes the change is triggered, you can change the image visibility on the one you want to disappear and the one you want to be shown.

If you have bootstrap installed, it is as easy as adding and removing a class via jQuery

**HTML**

```
<img src="" id="image1" alt="">
<img src="" id="image2" alt="" class="hidden">
<p id="change">Change</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#change").click(function () {
  $('#image1').addClass('hidden');
  $('#image2').removeClass('hidden');
});
```